# jQuery bind("load")

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var imgLoader = $("<img />");
$(imgLoader).attr("src", "http://localhost/malevil/Content/Images/img_adrenalin.jpg");

$(imgLoader).unbind('load');
$(imgLoader).bind('load', function () {
    alert("event fired");
});
```

But this work only in chrome, where is the problem ?
In IE, Firefox and Opera load event never fired.

Comment: Can you tell me if you have tried to bind the events before actually setting the source of the image?

Comment: I responded to the answer below

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to bind the load event before you set the `src` property.

As a side note, there are known issues with the load event on images that you need to be aware of:

- [javascript, image onload() doesnt fire in webkit if loading same image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5024111/javascript-image-onload-doesnt-fire-in-webkit-if-loading-same-image)

And, quoting from the [jQuery manual on  `load()`:](http://api.jquery.com/load-event)

> - It doesn't work consistently nor
>     reliably cross-browser
> - It doesn't
>     fire correctly in WebKit if the image
>     src is set to the same src as before
> - It doesn't correctly bubble up the
>     DOM tree
> - Can cease to fire for images
>     that already live in the browser's
>     cache

Answer (score 3):

I would set the handler **before** you set the `src` attribute --as it might be that the image loads before your event handler gets set.

Comment: haha this turned out to be the case for me for a similar issue.